# Geometry Nodes Fields - Semi Circle

Tags: normals, mathematics, geometry-nodes

Is it possible to create a semi-circle with Geometry Nodes?

It's for a particle system, so a math based approach rather than a boolean approach would be ideal to keep the vert count/calculation time down.

I've used the below method for a semi-circle but cant seem to get it to work for a single face circle. My thinking was that if I rotated the normal 90° the same approach would work, but I'm probably miss-understanding how normals work.[image][image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you make a face, all normals will point up:

[image]

So it is not useful information to sort vertices.

If you want to keep one face, you can basically shift points from one side:

[image]

You can also go nuts and recreate the half of a circle, so that the straight line will consist of 2 points:

[image]

Super easy node setup from Ratt, with usage of curve **Arc** primitive and then converted to mesh:

[image]

Comment: Why clamp X to -1000? The result seems like it's clamped to 0 

Comment: It is for saving X value as it is, Y will be from 0 to radius

Comment: Aaah thanks for clarifying, the axis are shown on the screenshot so I should have figured it by myself. It would be nice if nodes values supported infinities (or do they?)

Comment: Any particular reason for not just using arc curve primitive?

Comment: Well, nice suggestion=-)

Comment: @Crantisz thanks I wasn't sure if it was being avoided due to timing or w/e but it also avoids a potential crash from fill caps and deleted geometry https://developer.blender.org/T97831

Comment: I did not even know the arc existed :0

Comment: I feel like all these methods are good though, for different reasons. For some reason all of them are offset slightly when instanced to points inside my NG but thats another problem. Thanks for the knowledge!

Answer (score 4):

You can also do this using a curve circle, separating based on position instead of normal, then filling afterwards to make an N-Gon. Something like this:

[image: Semi Circle Node Graph]

Edit: As Ratt pointed out under Crantisz answer the arc primitive exists for this very purpose

[image: Arc is Better]

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to try implement the arc approach into my set up but I can see the curve approach being useful too.

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer to use the node `Arc` (Blender 3.1+)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**This is by far the worst solution**, but perhaps of some educational value (like what to avoid):

[image]

Left is triangle fill (notice overlapping face), right is n-gon fill:

[image]

Comment: Seems like a niche solution that someone might need for an obscure project in 5 years time.